# SCSS concatenating variables and string values results in quotations around the entire property value

Tags: string, variables, sass, concatenation

I am still learning SCSS and I am struggling a little with the syntax. I am trying to concatenate variable and strings in a single variable like so:

```
$border-width: 3px;
$border-color: #ccc;

$border-values: $border-width + ' solid ' + $border-color;

.box {
    left-border: $border-values;
}
```

This produces a set of quotes around the processed values like so:

```
border-left: "3px solid #ccc";
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
$border-values: unquote($border-width + " solid "  + $border-color);

.box {
 border-left: $border-values;;
}
```

the unquote function Removes quotes from a string. Check the [Official Doc](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#unquote-instance_method)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the extra variable, just use the values normally:

```
.box {
    left-border: $border-width solid $border-color;
}
```

But if you really want a `$border-values` variable, you might be able to do this (haven't tried):

```
$border-values: $border-width solid $border-color;

.box {
  left-border: $border-values;
}
```

Comment: You are probably right that i am over complicating this :P